# Scrolling is not smooth in Android, and gets stuck in the middle

Tags: android

I'm using the following code for displaying in list... it scrolls but not in a smooth way; like on the iPhone.

```
this.ListAdapter = new IndMessageAdapter(this,
    R.layout.individualmessage_list,
    IndividualMessage.CombinedMessages);

setListAdapter(this.ListAdapter);
```

Comment: Are you testing on Device or Emulator?

Comment: are you doing any actions in the list adapter, i.e. loading images remotely into imageview int the list, which might block the UI thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you are not reusing views in you adapter. Check this as example of adapter reusing views.

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html